# Transforming text in a "learned" way between Google Sheets cells?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to figure out how to reformat data in a programmatic way between cells in Google Sheets - sorry if that's an inelegant way of putting it but by way of example, I'd like to make a cell with the string value "LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME" turn into "FIRSTNAME.LASTNAME@GMAIL.COM" in the next cell over. Can someone walk me through a formula that can parse and reformat a cell like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ", "),,2)&"."&
 INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ", "),,1)&"@gmail.com"
```

[image: 0]

for arrayformula use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
 INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A, ", "),,2)&"."&
 INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A, ", "),,1)&"@gmail.com"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Oh man thanks so much! That first formula did exactly what I was looking for. Do you happen to have any resources for learning more about GS formulas like this? I'm a complete beginner to the more involved stuff...

Answer (score 1):

or try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,
 REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "([A-Z]+), ([A-Z]+)", "$2.$1")&"@gmail.com"))
```

[image: 0]